# Bootstrap Multiselect How To Check for NoN Selected Text or Value

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I can get the selected text from my Bootstrap Multiselect but i can't find the right syntax to check for Non-selection (which is the text prompt set in the option:

```
nonSelectedText
```

In my case the text prompt is "Choose One Or More".
We use:

```
$("#mymultiMnu option:selected").text()
```

to get the selected text items i thought we'd use the same to check for the prompt text thus denoting that the user hasn't made a  selection, like:

```
if(  $("#mymultiMnu  option:selected").text()!='Choose One Or More'  )
```

I've tried checking for ablank string "" and zero int (0) and zero string ("0") to no avail. Cannot see where this is documented on the developers site.

I really dont care if i check for the value or text as long as there's a safe way to detect the condition. Any ideas anyone???

Comment: Try `$("#mymultiMnu option:not(':selected')").text()`

Comment: Thanks for the idea ... didnt work but led me to get it working with:      `$("#mymultiMnu option:selected").length > 0`  - cheers

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)